# Android App Shortcuts Appear even after Uninstalling Anbox

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview, anbox

I uninstalled Anbox on my Ubuntu, but an Android app shortcut still appeared on dash.

[image: Android App Shortcut Still Appear Since I Uninstalled Anbox]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. You should find `.desktop` files associated to these Android apps somewhere.

Remove these `.desktop` files, corresponding application launchers should also be removed.